# How to extract values in a specific row range from Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, list, python-requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7i9e.png)

I want to print out all row values corresponding to a specific month in Excel using Python.
Please look at the picture.

If I put "2021.10" in the function value using the function, I want the values [2021.10.03", "2021.10.03", "2021.10.03", "2021.10.03","2021.10.03", None "2021.10.15", "2021.10.15", None] to be entered in the list.

Simply, if I put the value "2021.10" into the function, I would like to extract the values from rows 5 to 13 of column A.

What should I do?

---

I'm reading the sheet in openpyxl now.

```html
import openpyxl as oxl

load_excel = oxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Homework.xlsx',data_only = True)
load_sheet = load_excel['Sheet']
```

Comment: You want to the values [2021.10.03", "2021.10.03", "2021.10.03", "2021.10.03", None, "2021.10.15", and "2021.10.15"], it is not matched with the rows 5 ~ 13 in the pic. Which one do you want?

Comment: Are you reading an Excel file using a module, are you reading this as a CSV file, or are you driving a running copy of Excel?

Comment: Have you written any code at all? How are you reading the sheet currently?

Comment: Oh, I didn't enter the exact value of the list! I want to earn 5 to 13 lines. And I'm reading the sheet in openpyxl.

Comment: Can you clarify the rule in more detail? How the two None can be included? Do you want to include all None between rows starting with '2021.10' and following all None right after last value of '2021.10'?

Comment: Yes, that's what you said.

Answer (score 0):

This can extract rows as what you want

```
# dataframe from the excel file
             A     B  C
0   2021.09.23     E  1
1   2021.09.23     A  1
2   2021.09.23     E  1
3         None  None  3
4   2021.10.03     A  1
5   2021.10.03     A  2
6   2021.10.03     B  2
7   2021.10.03     E  1
8   2021.10.03     A  1
9         None  None  7
10  2021.10.15     A  2
11  2021.10.15     B  3
12        None  None  5
13  2021.11.03     C  2
14  2021.11.03     B  1
15  2021.11.03     F  2
```

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def extract(df, value):
    df = df.reset_index()  # to make index column
    first_index = df[(df['A'].str.startswith(value))].iloc[0]['index']  # to get index of first 2021.10 value
    last_index = df[(df['A'].str.startswith(value))].iloc[-1]['index']  # to get index of last 2021.10 value

    sub_df = df.iloc[first_index:last_index+1,]  # to make dataframe from first index to last index

    for i, row in df[last_index+1:].iterrows():
        # to add all None right after the last value
        if row['A'] == 'None':
            sub_df = sub_df.append(row)
        else:
            break
    print(sub_df['A'].to_list())

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Homework.xlsx')  # I read xlsx file using pandas instead of `openpyxl`
extract(df, '2021.10')
```

This will be printed by the function:

```
['2021.10.03', '2021.10.03', '2021.10.03', '2021.10.03', '2021.10.03', 'None', '2021.10.15', '2021.10.15', 'None']
```

In case that you want to read a excel file using openpyxl, you can change last three lines as follows:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)  # convert a data to Pandas dataframe
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]  # to use first row as column names
df = df.iloc[1:, :]  # to use the other rows as a data
extract(df, '2021.10')
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it in openpyxl?

Comment: @chlth I added a new way to read a excel file using `openpyxl`, but still made result using `Pandas`. If you want to do it without pandas, it would be completcated so I highly recommand to use `Pandas`. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a list first and then write a loop which will traverse the rows
which value you need. After every iteration you can append the value to the list.
after completing the loop you will get your desired extracted values.

```
list = []

for i,j in range of(3,10):
    list.append(sheet.cell(row=i, col=j).value = list[i][j])
```